# Transpose / reshape dataframe from long to wide format

Tags: r, transpose

I have a data frame that follows the below long Pattern:

```
studentInfo <- data.frame(University=c("A","B","C","B","A","D"),StudentID = c("S1","S1","S2","S2","S3","S3"),Subject = c("Maths", "Science", "English", "Maths", "History", "English"))

studentInfo<-data.table(studentInfo,keep.rownames = "FALSE")



    University   StudentID     Subject
1   A            S1            Maths
2   B            S1            Science
3   C            S2            English
4   B            S2            Maths
5   A            S3            History
6   D            S3            English

dcast (studentInfo,StudentID ~ Subject, value.var = "Subject")
```

I get the below:

```
 StudentID English History Maths Science
1:        S1    <NA>    <NA> Maths Science
2:        S2 English    <NA> Maths    <NA>
3:        S3 English History  <NA>    <NA>
```

I would like to get below:

```
    University  StudentID   S1     S3     S1      S2      S2      S3

1   A           S1          Maths                   
5   A           S3                 History              
2   B           S1                       Science            
4   B           S2                                Maths     
3   C           S2                                        English       
6   D           S3                                                English
```

I am new to coding in R. I am preparing a dataset to run Heatmap/Oncoprint. I have attempted using dcast of reshape2 and spread functions. But was not able to get the format I needed for the next step of my workflow.

Thanks

Comment: Ronak Shah answer was helpful though did not solve the issue. This code worked with my issue:                                                                                               studentInfo %>%.                                                                    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = "StudentID", values_from = "Subject")

Comment: Can you explain how the above worked with your issue? Can you check the expected output that you have shown in your question and the output that you get after using the above? Are they the same?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a column with row number and then get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)

studentInfo %>%
    mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(StudentID) %>%
    mutate(StudentID = paste(StudentID, row_number(), sep = "_")) %>%
    tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = StudentID, values_from = Subject) %>%
    select(-row)

# A tibble: 6 x 7
#  University S1_1  S1_2    S2_1    S2_2  S3_1    S3_2   
#  <chr>      <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>  
#1 A          Maths NA      NA      NA    NA      NA     
#2 B          NA    Science NA      NA    NA      NA     
#3 C          NA    NA      English NA    NA      NA     
#4 B          NA    NA      NA      Maths NA      NA     
#5 A          NA    NA      NA      NA    History NA     
#6 D          NA    NA      NA      NA    NA      English
```

It is not advisable to have dataframe with same column names.

Comment: Thank you. However, that does't solve my issue. Output should be the values from PatientID column (S1, S1,S2, S2, S3, S3 etc...) and not (S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6 etc...0

Comment: @KaoutherGhabriSt.Clair You cannot and should not have columns with same name. I have updated the answer to include column names such as `S3_1`, `S3_2` etc . Check if that helps.

Comment: That is not the output I need for my workflow.I used  wideData <- pivot_wider (Data, names_from = StudentID, values_from = Subject). I don't need the column with StudentID values in my new farme, anymore.

Comment: @KaoutherGhabriSt.Clair Can you explain how the above worked with your issue? Can you check the expected output that you have shown in your question and the output that you get after using the above? Are they the same?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dcast(studentInfo, University + StudentID ~ StudentID, value.var = 'Subject')
```